# How to use TabLayout with ViewPager2 in Android

Tags: java, android, androidx, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I want to use `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout` component with Android's new `ViewPager` implementation `androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2`. However, the `setupWithViewPager(..)` method provided by `TabLayout` supports only the old `ViewPager` implementation. Is there a way to bind a `TabLayout` to a `ViewPager2` component easily?

Comment: Perhaps this ViewPager2 sample from Google would help: https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/tree/master/ViewPager2

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You have to use [this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayoutMediator.java) `TabLayoutMediator` that mimics `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager()` and sets up the `ViewPager2` with `Tablayout`. Otherwise, you will have to write your own adapter that will combine both parties.

Its code will look like this in Kotlin

```
TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position ->
  tab.text = tabTitles[position]
}.attach()
```

Comment: Code to use this **TabLayoutMediator** is as follow:         
      `TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2) {                                                                 tab, position ->  viewPager2.setCurrentItem(tab.position, true)
            if (position == 1)
               tab.setText("Test2")
           if (position == 0)
                tab.setText("Test1")
        }.attach()`

Comment: anyone reading this should double check the material library version of their app. `TabLayoutMediator` is present in `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08' `,  but android studio had imported version `1.0.0` by default for me, which did not had this.

Comment: How can I set dots on the TabLayout (like a carousel), instead of numbers in tabs?

Comment: `viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.position, true)` is unnecessary and causes the 2nd tab to be selected and the pages to be swiped always!

Comment: @ericn you are right brother, setting current item is done swip itself.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Hi, you just have to    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
and yout tab_selector should provide different drwable for selected and unselected case

Comment: @anshsachdeva I am using thr latest 1.3.0-alpha02, but i can't find TablayoutMediator class

Comment: @ericn, if remove `viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.position, true)`, it will show tabs, but we won't have enough control over a fragment (for instance, won't filter a list in `RecyclerView`). So, it should be added.

Comment: If you call this method from `onCreateView`, make sure `viewPager != null` or will get NPE.

Comment: Forgot this attach() and wasted 20 min.

Answer (score 60):

### No hacks, no extensions, no TabLayoutMediator

I am on `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'` and do the following **without** needing the TabLayoutMediator.
Instead, I link the TabLayout with the ViewPager2 using the method described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout). I've also added a working example to github [here](https://github.com/sverbist/android-tablayout). I think I've minimized the solution to a minimal working example. I'll explain the important bits.

#### Adding the elements to the template

First we'll need to add the TabLayout and ViewPager2 to the layout. I've placed them inside a LinearLayout and CoordinatorLayout here, but you can do whatever you like of course.

```
<!-- activity_main.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### Connecting an adapter to the viewpager

So the adapter is in charge of supplying the correct fragments to the activity.
You'll have to extend [FragmentStateAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter) which I've done very simply as below (it's a private class because it's declared within my MainActivity.java here):

```
    private class ViewStateAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

        public ViewStateAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
            super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            // Hardcoded in this order, you'll want to use lists and make sure the titles match
            if (position == 0) {
                return new BarFragment();
            }
            return new FooFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            // Hardcoded, use lists
            return 2;
        }
    }
```

I can then connect my own Adapter to the ViewPager as below:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
ViewStateAdapter sa = new ViewStateAdapter(fm, getLifecycle());
final ViewPager2 pa = findViewById(R.id.pager);
pa.setAdapter(sa);
```

I've added the fragments to my viewpager. (Because I hardcoded the Fragments in my adapter, you should use a list and something like an 'addFragment' method or something)

#### The TabLayout

Then with

```
TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Bar"));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Foo"));
```

I add two tabs to my TabLayout, showing the titles but not letting me switch to the fragments yet.

#### Connecting TabLayout to Adapter

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                pa.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

This should be pretty straightforward. User clicks on a tab, I get the position in my callback and I simply set the adapter's current item to that position.

#### Change Tab when swiping

Finally we couple back when the user swipes the fragment to set the correct tab item as selected

```
pa.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice solution! Works as expected.

Comment: Good work. Appreciate the project on GitHub. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you tell me will the swiping between tabs cause the fragments to be recreated?

Answer (score 38):

## UPDATE

> ## check this [Create swipe views with tabs using ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2)

Here is the Updated answer **How to use TabLayout with ViewPager2 in Android**

## Now we no need to create a class from **`TabLayoutMediator`**

Use below **`dependencies`**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08'
implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-beta02'
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

> XMl layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/tabs"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> Activity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        viewpager.adapter = AppViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)

        TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewpager, object : TabLayoutMediator.OnConfigureTabCallback {
            override fun onConfigureTab(tab: TabLayout.Tab, position: Int) {
                // Styling each tab here
                tab.text = "Tab $position"
            }
        }).attach()


    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If your using  `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'` then use below code

```
        TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewpage,
        TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy { tab, position ->
            when (position) {
                0 -> { tab.text = "TAB ONE"}
                1 -> { tab.text = "TAB TWO"}
            }
        }).attach()
```

> **OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: anyone reading this should double check the material library version of their app. this version worked for me, but android studio had imported version 1.0.0 by default which did not had this

Comment: @anshsachdeva same, I cannot find TabLayoutMediator class in com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha08, com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha09.

Comment: @Seyid-KananBagirov it is present in implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08' (notice the version 1.1.0-alpha08 and not 1.0.0)

Comment: in 1.1.0-alpha10 they renamed `TabLayoutMediator.OnConfigureTabCallback` to `TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy`

Comment: I am getting an unresolved reference for `AppViewPagerAdapter`?

Comment: @crmepham you need to create `AppViewPagerAdapter` class like this https://github.com/RathodNilesh14/TabLayout-with-viewpager2-/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/nilu/demoapplication/AppViewPagerAdapter.kt

Comment: @Almighty I have to just rename it and that's it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes, please check the updated answer

Comment: @NileshRathod Thank you. Why do we have to specify TabConfigurationStrategy ? It's marked as non-null, but I actually don't need to do anything for the callback. To me it's empty...

Comment: also tabl;ayoutmediatar is unsupported now, we should use some other method to attach tablayout and viewpager 2

Comment: In the accepted answer we also have `viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.position, true)`. It makes more control over fragments.

Comment: the new way to connect viewpager2 and tablayout also solve issue where we will get crash if still using the old way to connect viewpager2 and tablayout when I turned on ProGuard

Answer (score 23):

Initialize the `TabLayoutMediator` object with an object of `TabLayout`, `ViewPager2` , `autoRefresh` -- boolean type, and an object of `OnConfigurationChangeCallback`.

```
TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2, true, new TabLayoutMediator.OnConfigureTabCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onConfigureTab(TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
    // position of the current tab and that tab  
  }
});
```

Finally just call `attach()` to the `TabLayoutMediator` object *to wire up the tablayout to the viewpager* :-

```
 tabLayoutMediator.attach();
```

`autoRefresh` - key if set to `true` -- ( By default its set to true )

> **`RECREATES`** all the tabs of the `tabLayout` if `notifyDataSetChanged` is called to the viewpager `adapter`.

Use the contents of [TabLayoutMediator.java](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-viewpager2/blob/master/app/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/integration/testapp/TabLayoutMediator.java)

Answer (score 9):

You can use Kotlin extension function:

```
fun TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager2, labels: List<String>) {

    if (labels.size != viewPager.adapter?.itemCount)
        throw Exception("The size of list and the tab count should be equal!")

    TabLayoutMediator(this, viewPager,
        TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy { tab, position ->
            tab.text = labels[position]
        }).attach()
}
```

And call it:

```
 tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, listOf("Tab A", "Tab B"))
```

Comment: What dependency do I need to add in order to use this extension fun?

Comment: There is not any dependency except Kotlin in order to use extension functions :)

Comment: Yeah, I know. I meant what Android KTX artifact must I add in order to use this extension function. Also I don't have `setupWithViewPager(ViewPager2, List)` available – I only have `setupWithViewPager(ViewPager)`

Comment: You should implement ViewPager2 (androidx.viewpager2:1.0.0) and matarial components (com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03) as artifact to able to use this extension function.

Comment: And i also recommend to use ViewPager2 instead of old ViewPager component.

Comment: Yeah I had those artifacts included and that extension function wasn't available. I somehow got it working without using that extension func. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

If you're coding in JAVA. You can use the following adapter for the viewPager2:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
  private static final int CARD_ITEM_SIZE = 10;
  public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
    super(fragmentActivity);
  }
  @NonNull @Override public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    return CardFragment.newInstance(position);
  }
  @Override public int getItemCount() {
    return CARD_ITEM_SIZE;
  }
}
```

And on the mainActivity you need to have something inline with the following:

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(this));
    new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,
        new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
          @Override public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
            tab.setText("Tab " + (position + 1));
          }
        }).attach();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

it is very simple:

**java code:**

```
tabLayout=findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager=findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(this));

    new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
            if (position==0){
                tab.setText(R.string.photos);
                tab.view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_rectangle_1345));
            }
            else {
                tab.setText(R.string.videos);
            }
        }
    }).attach();

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.view.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_rectangle_1345));
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

**adapter:**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
    super(fragmentActivity);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    if (position==0) {
        return new PhotosFragment();
    }
    else {
        return new VideosFragment();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 2;
}}
```

**XML:**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@color/tool_bar_bg"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/collection_bar" />

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If your tab title comes from `string.xml`.
You can put the `fragment` with `title` together in a `List` then set title by `TabLayoutMediator`. It helps you easily to reorder, delete or add new fragment

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(...): View? {
        ...

        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = pagerAdapter.getTabTitle(position)
        }.attach()
    }

    private inner class PagerAdapter(fa: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {
        val pages = listOf(
            Pair(HomeFragment.newInstance(), R.string.home),
            Pair(GraphFragment.newInstance(), R.string.graph),
            Pair(SettingFragment.newInstance(), R.string.setting),
        )

        override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
            return pages[position].first
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return pages.count()
        }

        fun getTabTitle(position: Int): String {
            return getString(pages[position].second)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You layouts are ready, fragments are ready and Adapters are ready.
All you need now is to setup an event listener to

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

This should bind the Tab layout to your ViewPager2.

Answer (score 0):

Im running mine on the implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1' and didn't use the tabLayoutMediator either. For starters the https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings have changed for the TabLayout in androidX so be sure to be using com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout in your import statement.
Heres the rest of my implementation of the solution:
The Xml layout declaration of the viewPager and the TabLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/tan_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/tabs"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the activity file

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity to use the activity_main.xml layout file
        setContentView(layout.activity_main);

        // Find the view pager that will allow the user to swipe between fragments
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        // Create an adapter that knows which fragment should be shown on each page
        SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new SimpleFragmentPagerAdapter(this,getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set the adapter onto the view pager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Find the tab layout that shows the tabs
        TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        // Connect the tab layout with the view pager. This will
        //   1. Update the tab layout when the view pager is swiped
        //   2. Update the view pager when a tab is selected
        //   3. Set the tab layout's tab names with the view pager's adapter's titles
        //      by calling onPageTitle()
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

I used a fragment adapter setup in a different class as well where I passed the context to the constructor for the different Tabs

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use TabLayoutMediator `after your set adapter to view_pager2`

```
TabLayoutMediator(tab_layout, view_pager2) { tab, position ->
                tab.text = fragmentList[position].second  // here u can modify you text..
            }.attach()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take inspiration from my sample project to create UIs with Viewpager2. I use `TabLayoutMediator` on all examples, Simple and very useful. 
https://github.com/gabriel-TheCode/OnboardingViewPagerExamples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **Kotlin extension function**:

```
fun TabLayout.setupWithViewPager2(viewPager: ViewPager2) {
    val labels = (0 until tabCount).mapNotNull { getTabAt(it)?.text.toString() }

    TabLayoutMediator(this, viewPager) { tab, position ->
        tab.text = labels[position]
    }.attach()
}
```

Usage:

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager2(viewPager2)
```