# Unresolved reference: TabLayoutMediator

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I am developing an android application which needs a `TabLayout` bind to a `ViewPager2`. Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372259/how-to-use-tablayout-with-viewpager2-in-android) and following the code in [here](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/viewpager2/), I need to use `TabLayoutMediator`. But when importing it, I face `Unresolved reference` error. I know what this error refers to but I cannot find any problem in dependencies and stuff which causes the error. As mentioned in the second link, this class is contained in `androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-beta03` which is a newer version of what the link talks about. I also tried to downgrade the version to the one mentioned in the link but it did not work as well. Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-beta03'
}
```

And This is my `MainActivity` file:

```
package com.example.myapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val viewpager : ViewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
        val demoAdapter = DemoViewPagerAdapter(this)
        viewpager.adapter = demoAdapter

        val tabs : TabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout)
        TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewpager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = demoAdapter.getPageTitle(position)
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: Have you did [`clean/rebuild project`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28581211/how-to-project-clean-in-android-studio/28581254#28581254)? If it did not work just invalidate cache and restart again it should work.

Comment: Also since you are using `Kotlin` you can import this `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*` so you can avoid the `findViewById()` thingy

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Yes I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project. Nothing changed.

Comment: Can you just change your dependencies to these : 
`implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07"`
`implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-alpha05"`

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Yeah it worked! but how is it possible that the newer versions of these two dependencies cause the problem?!

Comment: because you were not using newer dependency. your gradle had `'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`  (notice the version `1.0.0`). `TablayoutMediator` is added in `1.1.0` i guess

Comment: @anshsachdeva usinf latest 1.3.0-alpha02  but can not include tablayout mediator

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I recommend you to read this [`Styling Android ViewPager tutorial`](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/viewpager2/) it explains how to work with what you are looking for, as I can see you are not using the same imports to work with, may you use these instead :

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07"
implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0-alpha05"
```

> but how is it possible that the newer versions of these two dependencies cause the problem?!

You have to check the change logs for these library to see what happens, you were using the `Beta` versions though.

This is the [`Github repository`](https://github.com/StylingAndroid/ViewPager2)