# how to override and display title of tabs in viewpager2 in tablayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I am using a `TabLayout` inside a `Fragment`. The content of the `TabLayout` (made of 2 `fragments`) is displayed but not the title of the `tabs`. I believe it's a layout problem but i'm not sure on how to fix it.
Also what would be the overrided method for `ViewPager2`  that was used in `ViewPager` (`getPagetitle`) ?

*main Fragment*

```java
    public class CommunityFragment extends Fragment {
    
        private TabLayout tbL;
        private ViewPager2 vp;
        private RecipeViewPagerAdapter rvpa;
    
        public CommunityFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }
    
        public static CommunityFragment newInstance(){
            return new CommunityFragment();
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community, container, false);
            tbL = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabL);
            vp = rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            rvpa = new RecipeViewPagerAdapter(this);
            vp.setAdapter(rvpa);
    
            rvpa.addFragment(new AllFragment(),"All time");
            rvpa.addFragment(new DayFragment(),"Today");
            new TabLayoutMediator(tbL, vp, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
                        @Override public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                            //////title????
                        }
                    }).attach();
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

*Adapter*

```java
    public class RecipeViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    
        private ArrayList<Fragment> listF = new ArrayList<>();
        private ArrayList<String> listT =  new ArrayList<>();
    
        public RecipeViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
            super(fragment);
        }
    
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            return listF.get(position);
        }
        //new method ????
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
            return listT.get(position);
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return listT.size();
        }
    
        public void addFragment(Fragment frag, String title){
            listF.add(frag);
            listT.add(title);
        }
    }
```

*fragment layout*

```xml
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".fragments.CommunityFragment">
    
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabL"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/yellowCool"/>
    
        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372259/how-to-use-tablayout-with-viewpager2-in-android.

Answer (score 4):

put this in your main activity....

```
myAdapter=new FragmentAdapter(this);
myViewPager2.setAdapter(myAdapter);
       
String [] tabTtiles={"Home","Chat","Notification","Account"};
new TabLayoutMediator(myTabLayout, myViewPager2,(myTabLayout, position) -> 
  myTabLayout.setText(tabTtiles[position])).attach();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following adapter for the viewPager2:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
  private static final int CARD_ITEM_SIZE = 10;
  public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
    super(fragmentActivity);
  }
  @NonNull @Override public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    return CardFragment.newInstance(position);
  }
  @Override public int getItemCount() {
    return CARD_ITEM_SIZE;
  }
}
```

on the mainActivity you need to have something inline with the following:

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(this));
    new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,
        new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
          @Override public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
            tab.setText("Tab " + (position + 1));
          }
        }).attach();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your tabLayout doesn't display. Use this:

```
<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
     android:id="@+id/pager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1" // add this line
/>
```

TabLayoutMediator:

```
new TabLayoutMediator(tbL, vp, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
                    @Override public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                        if(position == 0)
                           tab.setText("All time");
                        else
                           tab.setText("Today");
                    }
                }).attach();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything. Could it be that the TabLayout doesnt have enough space to be visible ?

Comment: you should use like this =>  tab.setText("Tab1")

Answer (score 0):

**As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration#java):**

> The TabLayoutMediator object also handles the task of generating page
>   titles for the TabLayout object, which means that the adapter class
>   does not need to override getPageTitle():

And to do that:

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,
            (tab, position) -> tab.setText("OBJECT " + (position + 1))
    ).attach();
```