# Is there a way to set a title and subtitle for com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout Tab?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
TabLayoutMediator(
            tabbedFragmentView.tabs,tabbedFragmentView.view_pager)
 { tab, position ->
            tab.text = tabFragmentList[position].title
 }.attach()
```

I could not find a way to set a subtitle, there is only one set text function available it would be the main title for the tab layout tab what if I want a subtitle too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a custom view for the tab:

```
TabLayoutMediator(tabbedFragmentView.tabs, tabbedFragmentView.view_pager) { tab, position -> 
    val customTabView = View() // inflate your custom view here
    // set title and subtitle
    tab.setCustomView(customTabView)
}.attach()
```

Answer (score 0):

tabLayout with viewpager2 :
you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372259/how-to-use-tablayout-with-viewpager2-in-android/57230339)

```
TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position ->
tab.text = tabTitles[position]
viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.position, true)
}.attach()
```