# How to use SlidingTabLayout to show (by highlight) in which fragment we are?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, highlight

I'm working on an Android Studio app and I would like to hava an indicator of in which fragment user is.
There is 4 pages, each one with some fragments and I would like to highlight the fragment where user is (the yellow bar)

[image]

Actually, the yellow bar don't move when fragment change.
Is it possible to make changement automatic or have I to programm the bar for each fragment ?
I don't know if it can help, but I use androidx and ViewPager2

```
public void setUp(final FormActivity context, final Toolbar toolbar, final Spinner spinner, final DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final ViewPager2 pager, final SlidingTabLayout tabs, FragmentActivity supportFragmentActivity) {
        this.drawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        this.pager = pager;
        this.tabs = tabs;
        this.progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

In the .xml file :

```
<pack.myrhs.views.NVHeaderTextView
android:id="@+id/progressBar"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/drawer_side_margin
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/drawer_side_margin"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/drawer_divider_margin"
android:text="loading..."
android:textColor="@color/textIconsColor"
android:visibility="gone" />
```

And that's the NVHeaderTextView class:

```
public class NVHeaderTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    public NVHeaderTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        if(isInEditMode())
            return;

        String fontName = "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf";

        Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontName);
        setTypeface(typeface);
        setTextSize(14);
        setTextColor(Color.argb((int) (255 * 1.00), 255, 255, 255));


        int flags = getPaintFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG
                | Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG;
        setPaintFlags(flags);

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I'm using SlidingTabLayout, so the TabLayoutMediator doesn't work (it seems to me).
I'm now, using the setViewPager() method:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void params) {

            pager.setAdapter(adapter);

            tabs.setViewPager(pager);

            if (adapter != null)
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            cancel(true);
        }
```

Thanks for advance.

Comment: Can you share your code? if you set it up correctly using ViewPager and TabLayout, it should work.

Comment: I don't really know what part of the code is needed. The app wasn't mine at first and there is too much files for I gave you all. All I can say you is that there is a fragment for each page (A,B,C,D), there is an adapter where I build the ArraList<Fragment> frags which one I add the four fragments. The progress bar is declared in my navigation drawer

Comment: Doesn't this answer question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372259/how-to-use-tablayout-with-viewpager2-in-android

Comment: @momvart thanks, it help me by lead me to understand that it's the tabLayout which do what I need. But I'm using SlidingTabLayout, so I can't apply the TabLayoutMediator

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

I finally solve my problem by switching my SlindingTabLayout to TabLayout.

In my `setUp()` method for my pages:

```
// Creation of the link between the tabLayout and the pager
    tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected (TabLayout.Tab tab){
            pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected (TabLayout.Tab tab){
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected (TabLayout.Tab tab){
        }
    });
    pager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected ( int position){
            tabs.selectTab(tabs.getTabAt(position));
        }
    });
```

With the init of the tabs for each page:

```
    drawerPageListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

            if (currentPage != position) {

                if (position != 1) { //not page2
                    //TOOLBAR
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                adapter = null;

                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        adapter = pageOneAdapter;
                        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.page1));
                        currentPage = 0;
                        // Set up of the TabLayout
                        tabs.removeAllTabs();
                        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("A"));
                        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("B"));
                        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("C"));
                        tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText("D"));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
```